# Log all reject promises in Q

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Is there a way to configure Q to log or call a specific function on all rejected promises (like an interceptor)?

Many exceptions are being swallowed in my application, and put error handling in all my promises just for logging purposes would be duplicated work to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Since V1.3 [unhandled rejection tracking](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/pull/643) is available in Q

Comment: @Bergi I think OP wants to `tap` all the rejections, I guess. That is not available, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye: I understood he only wants to intercept the otherwise swallowed ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q actually already supports this - as of 1.3.0 Q offers the [standard unhandled rejection hooks](https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/0237932cee84712951a2):

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(reason, p) {
  console.log("Unhandled rejection detected ", reason, p);
});
```

You can also log [caught errors from `.done` with `Q.onerror`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qonerror):

```
Q.onerror = function(error){
    // errors will be here and not thrown in `done` chains.
};
```

Comment: `Q.onerror` is also for uncaught errors only, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye yes, but for _handled_ uncaught ones - that is - ones you implicitly caught by writing a `.done()`.

Comment: Great that what I was looking for. Is there a way to print the error stack trace if available?

Comment: @RicardoMayerhofer yes, the `reason` parameter is the error you rejected with and you can print its stack trace - be sure to enable long stack traces (Q.longStackTraces = true) at the top of your code.