# How can I convert a rejected promise to an exception and throw it from an Express route handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, q

In one of my app's route handlers, I am calling a method that returns a Q promise. Rather than handling the rejection using the `.catch` method, I want it to be thrown and get caught by my Express app's catch-all error handler.

I tried Q's `done` method, but it throws the exception asynchronously, so rather than it getting handled by my catch-all error handler, it gets propagated all the way up and my app gets terminated:

```
// The route handler 

function index(req, res) {
    dao.findById(id).then(function (data) {
        res.send(data);
    }).done();
}

// The catch all event-handler

function catchAllErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err, req, res);
}

// Registration of the catch-all event handler

app.use(catchAllErrorHandler);
```

The error never enters the catch all error handler. Is there a way to make the thrown errors get handled by `catchAllErrorHandler`?

Comment: How about changing your `index` function to include `next` (as a third parameter), then changing `.done()` to `.catch(next)`

Comment: @major-mann if I pass a parameter to `next`, is it considered an error?

Comment: I think your solution works. If you post it as a solution I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, passing a parameter to next is the way to explicitly pass errors. I will post the solution when I get off mobile :)

Comment: No worries. And I no longer _think_ your solution works. I know it works. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not answer your question directly, but rather shows another way to achieve your goal.

Every middleware handler in express has the signature `(request, response, next)`. Currently your `index` function does not have next defined.

When calling next with an argument, express considers that argument to be an error, and manages it appropriately.

So, in your case, change your `index` function to include the next parameter, and change `.done()` to `.catch(next)` which will call next with any error that occurs, and allow express to handle it.

```
dao.findById(id)
   // Handle success
    .then(function (data) {
        res.send(data);
    })
    // Handle failure
    .catch(next);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I tried Q's done method

That's probably the best you get to throw exceptions from promises.

> but it throws the exception asynchronously

Of course it does, promises are always asynchronous. You cannot determine whether your promise will reject in the future and synchronously throw an exception…

> Is there a way to make the thrown errors get handled by `catchAllErrorHandler`?

Pass the handler explicitly as a handler:

```
dao.findById(id).then(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
}).catch(catchAllErrorHandler);
```

Alternatively, since Q v1.3 you can used the [unhandled rejection tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30834898/1048572) and put your `catchAllErrorHandler` there.

Comment: The catch-all error handler is a _middleware_, defined elsewhere in the code, and injected using `app.use`. So this solution won't work for me.

Comment: Ah, in that case you probably just want to `.catch(…)` exceptions and pass them to `next`.